# Managing dependencies for GNU radio to compile from source

Tags: python, dependencies, compiling, cmake, gnuradio

Ettus research gives a [big list of dependencies](https://kb.ettus.com/Building_and_Installing_the_USRP_Open-Source_Toolchain_(UHD_and_GNU_Radio)_on_Linux) for 18.04 which almost works for compiling gnu radio from source.

cmake gives the following config error:

```
-- Python checking for PyQt5 - found
-- Checking for module 'Qt5Qwt6'
--   No package 'Qt5Qwt6' found
-- QWT Version: 6.1.3
-- Found Qwt: /usr/lib/libqwt.so
```

However based on the packages I have (seems like every possible version.. perhaps too many) I should have what it needs.

```
apt-cache search qwt
libqwt-dev - Qt widgets library for technical applications (development, qt4)
libqwt-doc - Qt widgets library for technical applications (documentation)
libqwt-headers - Qt widgets library for technical applications (header files)
libqwt-qt5-6 - Qt widgets library for technical applications (runtime, qt5)
libqwt-qt5-dev - Qt widgets library for technical applications (development, qt5)
libqwt5-doc - Qt widgets library for technical applications (documentation)
libqwt5-qt4 - Qt4 widgets library for technical applications (runtime)
libqwt5-qt4-dev - Qt4 widgets library for technical applications (development)
libqwt6abi1 - Qt widgets library for technical applications (runtime, qt4)
libqwtmathml-dev - Text Engine for Qwt (development, qt4)
libqwtmathml-qt5-6 - Text Engine for Qwt (runtime, qt5)
libqwtmathml-qt5-dev - Text Engine for Qwt (development, qt5)
libqwtmathml6abi1 - Text Engine for Qwt (runtime, qt4)
libqwtplot3d-doc - 3D plotting library based on Qt/OpenGL (documentation)
libqwtplot3d-qt5-0 - 3D plotting library based on Qt5/OpenGL (runtime)
libqwtplot3d-qt5-dev - 3D plotting library based on Qt5/OpenGL (development)
python-guiqwt - efficient 2D data-plotting library - Python 2
python-guiqwt-doc - efficient 2D data-plotting library - Documentation
python-qwt - Pure Python implementation of Qwt - Python 2
python-qwt5-doc - Python Qwt5 technical widget library, documentation and examples
python-qwt5-qt4 - Python version of the Qwt5 technical widget library
python3-guiqwt - efficient 2D data-plotting library - Python 3
python3-qwt - Pure Python implementation of Qwt - Python 3
python-qwt-doc - Pure Python implementation of Qwt - Documentation
```

How can I edit the cmake list to properly find what it's looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching the Internet for *No package 'Qt5Qwt6' found*, I found that the `gnuradio` issue tracker shows this issue, and a [recommended solution](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/issues/2208#issuecomment-470692964):

> For the record `-DQWT_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib/libqwt.so` is needed on arch to make the gnuradion cmake script enable `gr-qtgui`.

Here, *arch* refers to ArchLinux, but that doesn't mean this solution is isolated to ArchLinux and could very well work for you.

Comment: I'll try this workaround out, I dismissed it before because it's for Arch but you're right, it might still work.

Comment: **Especially** with how new this issue is, and the fact that typically issues are found in ArchLinux first, as it's pretty cutting edge, etc.  Thank you for giving it a go and be sure to specify you tried this if it doesn't work.

Comment: it fixed part of the issue, qwt is now found. thanks!

Comment: Great. @n0rbert has a great suggestion.  Please take a look to understand their suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I'll recommend to use APT-driven method. The GNU Radio [is packaged with plugins](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/gnuradio) on Ubuntu. And at first to start with using binary package as simple as:

```
sudo apt-get install gnuradio
```

It was packaged by compilation, the compilation requires build-time dependencies. You can get them with the following actions:

1. Open Software & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`) and enable *Source code* repositories here
2. Install build-dependencies with simple command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get build-dep gnuradio
   ```

   The command above will install build-time dependencies for GNU Radio 3.7.11-10 (as in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS). This version is not too new as from [official site](https://www.gnuradio.org/) (news from 2018-07-15 contain announce of GNU Radio v3.7.13.4 Release).
3. Get GNU Radio source of 3.7.11-10 from the Ubuntu repository with simple command

   ```
   apt-get source gnuradio
   ```

   and patch/change/update it as you want.

Comment: This looks great, but I've experienced issues with `gnuradio` and this method in the past.  I am hopeful that this is working now and can be used successfully.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, 'apt install gnuradio' works pretty good for that version. I was trying to compile straight from the gnu radio git repo.